# The first time a TableView row is selected, it does not respond

Tags: tableview

I wrote a simple app with two view controllers:

- TableViewController with a table of websites to select
- ViewController with a WKWebView that loads the website. This ViewController also has a key-value observer that refuses to load websites not in an approvedWebsites array that is filled from the TableViewController upon selecting a website.

Here's the most relevant code, can add more as requested. This is the didSelectRowAt function in TableViewController:

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Browser") as? ViewController {
            vc.approvedWebsites = websites
            vc.selectedWebsite = websites[indexPath.row]
            navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

        }
```

Currently, when I run the program and select any row, that row will remain highlighted and not respond. I added a print function to the row (above the if let) and it will not print.

However, the next row I select will respond, but with the website from the row I previously selected. I've tested this vigorously and it always will load the website of what I selected previous. When I back out of the webView screen, it'll reset everything and I can recreate the same error without reloading the app.

Any ideas as to what's happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out. Make sure you used DidSelectRowAt not DidDeselectRowAt.